# Modifying a Date variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to create a schedule type check.

I want to check today's date and if it's not the correct Day of the week for a task to run it continues.

Once the day is correct, I will then create a timer based on the difference between the expected execution time (let's say 01:00) and now. I have had a few ideas on how to achieve this, one of them being below. The problem I am facing is I am unsure of how to create a CountDown timer from the `NEW-TIMESPAN` output and how to dynamically change the `$EndDate` time value to meet the relevant schedule value. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
$date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday')
{
    $StartDate = (GET-DATE)
     # I am unsure of how to dynamically change the $EndDate variable time value and create the 'CountDown variable' from the New-TimSpan output.
    $EndDate = [datetime]"11/13/2020 01:00" 
    $countdown = NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate
}
Write-Host $date
```

**EDIT**

With some help from @AdminOfTHings I have come up with the following solution.

```
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq $schedule.Day)
{
    $StartDate = (GET-DATE)
    $tempDate = (GET-DATE).ToString()
    $tempDate, $tempTime = $tempDate.Split(' ')
    [datetime]$DateTime = $tempDate + " $($schedule.Time)"
    $Timer = NEW-TIMESPAN -End $DateTime
    $CountDown = $Timer.TotalSeconds
    while ($CountDown -gt 0)
    {
        sleep 1
        $CountDown--
    }
    else
    {
        #START SERVICE
    }
}
```

Comment: `New-Timespan` doesn't need `-Start` if the starting time is now. Is the execution time always the same? You could just use `New-Timespan -Hours 8` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I have no idea why I didn't think of it before but I have come up with

```
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday') 

{   
     $StartDate = (GET-DATE)
     $tempDate = (GET-DATE).ToString() 
     $tempDate, $tmpTime = $tempDate.Split(' ')
     datetime]$DateTime = $tempDate + " $($schedule.Time)"
     $Timer = NEW-TIMESPAN -End $DateTime 
}
```

Just need to understand how to use the timer now (all in seconds)

Answer (score 1):

`New-Timespan`creates a `TimeSpan` object regardless of the parameter set being used. If you know how long a timespan should be, then you can statically create that combination of days, hours, minutes, and seconds, making end time irrelevant.

```
$date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday') {
    $countdown = New-Timespan -Hours 8
}
```

You could have a situation where you know you want the task to span 2 days but want it to end at `01:00`. This would make the total time variable. You can make adjustments based on start time:

```
$date = Get-Date -DisplayHint Date
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday') {
    $end = Get-Date -Day $date.AddDays(2).Day -Month $date.AddDays(2).Month -Hour 1 -Minute 0 -Second 0
    $countdown = New-TimeSpan -End $end
}
```

**Edit:**

If you reach a target day of week and want to create a timer that lasts until the next `01:00` hour from that point in time, you can do the following:

```
$date = Get-Date
if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday') {
    if ($date.Hour -lt 1) {
        # dynamic end date - start date
        $countdown = (Get-Date $date -Hour 1 -Minute 0 -Second 0) - $date
    } else {
        # dynamic end date - start date
        $countdown = (Get-Date $date.AddDays(1) -Hour 1 -Minute 0 -Second 0) - $date
    }
}
$countdown.TotalSeconds # total seconds of the time span
```

As an aside, if you expect the starting time to be now, you can skip the `-Start` parameter. Leaving off `-Start` assumes the starting time is now.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I know what hours to put in `-Hours`? It seems I would still need to dynamically identify the time difference between now and the expected execution time? Apologies if I am missing something

Comment: How do you determine *expected execution time*? There must be logic there that we can code.

Comment: O you added more since my comment post. Apologies if my question doesnt now make sense

Comment: I am using a YAML config to catch expected execution. So let's say Every Friday at 01:00. This being the time the execution of whatever process runs. It will run until it finishes.

Comment: Let's say for example, today is Friday and the time is 12:00. Do you expect the task to run for 6 more days then to the next Friday?

Comment: No, it will run until it completes. Let me explain some of the logic, this will be a service. So it will enter Pause state once execution completes. In the Pause, it will be doing checks for scheduling via the config file. Once it hits correct Day Time, it will unpause and start itself again. So the `countdown` variable once it hits 0 the time should be 01:00 on whatever date. The service then takes itself out of Pause and starts its run. Once completed, it places itself back into pause.

Comment: What does the relevant schedule value look like? What format is it in and how is it determined?

Comment: It's in YAML format, it simply tells me if it's a Weekly, Daily Monthly check. The Day of the week, Friday for example, and the expected execution Time 01:00 for example. All I really need to understand is how to dynamically modify the `$EndDate`. This should allow me to create the timer (seconds preferably). Unless of course, you can suggest a better method?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have no idea why I didn't think of it before but I have come up with `if ($date.DayOfWeek -eq 'Friday')
{
 $StartDate = (GET-DATE)
 $tempDate = (GET-DATE).ToString()
 $tempDate, $tmpTime = $tempDate.Split(' ')
 [datetime]$DateTime = $tempDate + " $($schedule.Time)"
 $Timer = NEW-TIMESPAN -End $DateTime
}` Just need to understand how to use the timer now (all in seconds)